# Starting API without opening browser

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I would like to start my WebAPI without opening the browser window. However I do would like to be able to manually go to the address to see the documentation of my API. Any tips?

Comment: What are you hosting on? AFAIK IIS has an option to start APPs non-lazy.

Comment: I'm using Owin.hosting to host my API

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually run a 'headless API' (or start API without a webpage popping up) and are using the default (C#/.Net 6.0) **"ASP.NET Core Web API"** template in Visual Studio 2022 and have created the Web API out of the box, all you need to do is set '`launchBrowser`' setting under `profiles` (in \Properties\launchSettings.json) to **false**.

Depending on your configuration/settings - you could still access Swagger by opening a browser to the `https://localhost:nnnn/swagger/index.html` address.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I used this: 
 `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Http://localhost:765/swagger");`

I've removed this line and now starts without opening the browser